# Why does chrome dev tools show the extension ID blow the iFrames?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

Normally, when I use the `Console` tab of the developer tools in Chrome, I see a list of iFrames like the following:

[image]

However, after I installed a certain extension I see the extension ID below a number of iFrames in the `Console` tab like following:

[image]

1. Can anybody tell me what does that mean? I suppose that those iFrames' parent is the extension but I am not sure. Can anyone please correct me if I am wrong?
2. Also, if those iFrames' parent is the extension is there any way to track them? By track them I mean that say I want to run the command `window.open = function () { debugger; }` for all such frames, is it possible for me to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at are the extensions content scripts. They are actually loaded as a child of either each tab or (in the case of this extension) each iFrame.

If you select one in the console, and do:

```
> chrome.runtime.getManifest()
```

The most relevant output is:

```
 { ...
 content_scripts: Array[1]
  0: Object
    all_frames: true
    js: Array[#]
       0: "content.js"
       ...
```

Here, the all_frames is the reason you see the extension repeated after each frame instead of once under the tab's main window.

(There may also be a background, which you can inspect from the extension's listing in settings.)

To debug content Scripts, there is actually a tab under the Developer Console->Sources. Here I have set a breakpoint on a specific line during the content scripts initialization (after expanding the code with the "{}" icon):

[image: Breakpoint on a Content Script]

When changing an iFrame or reloading the entire window, each content script then pauses at this point while the developer tools are open.

There are some [content script limits](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), so you should not be able to arbitrarily execute code in one iFrame from another though there is a message passing system which can achieve similar results if listeners are specifically setup.

Comment: Sorry about not accepting it earlier. I didn't have the chance to verify it.